# How to Reset windows 10 password using PIN code

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

I am already logged in to my windows 10 and trying to restore an older backup image

When I did that, it asked me for my password which I have never used because I have been using my PIN.

- I want to know how to reset Windows 10 password.  I know the pin and I can login.
- I have tried using **Change password** option, but I don't know what my current password is.
- I reset my **Hotmail** account that is linked to my computer but when I use its password to login, I get `invalid password`

Is there a way I can use security question or use the PIN to reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Go to Computer Management > Users > Set Password

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it using Command Prompt.

1. Login using PIN
2. Open Command Prompt in Administrator Mode
3. Type in `net user "%UserName%" NewPassword` to reset this users password.
4. To change UserX's password `net user UserX NewPassword`